# golang: read cmd line arguments and additional parameters

Tags: go, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am attempting to read the extra parameter passed to `go build.go build example-service` using the code below -

```
flag.Parse()

fmt.Println(flag.Args()) // Print "[build example-service]"

for _, cmd := range flag.Args() {
    switch cmd {
    case "build":
      log.Println("build", cmd) // Print "build build"
    }
}
```

I am successfully able to print `flag.Args()` as `[build example-service]` which is an `array` object

I unable to retrieve the `example-service` arg inside the switch `case` as `cmd` only prints `build build`

Comment: `go build` compiles the code to an executable.  It does not execute the code.   Please show exactly what commands  you're running

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is the "Command-Line Arguments" topic. More information: https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments

`os` package can use for this purpose. By `os.Args` array, `exe` file address (first index) and arguments (other indexes) are accessible.

Also to run your file using a command like this `go run test.go arg1 arg2 arg3...`. Here `test.go` is my test filename.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Input args are %v and type is %T", os.Args, os.Args)
}
```

The output of this code after running the `go run test.go build example-service` command is something like this:

```
Input args are [...\test.exe build example-service] and type is []string
```

And your code can modified to:

```
for _, cmd := range os.Args {
    switch cmd {
    case "build":
        log.Println("command: ", cmd)
    case "example-service":
        log.Println("command: ", cmd)
    }
}
```